# Can't vt Switch in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

I'm trying to use the ctrl+alt+n (1-6) to switch to a terminal in Kubuntu 15.04 but it doesn't work. Nothing happens.

When I run `ps au | grep tty` this is what I see.

```
root      1141  0.3  0.7 200760 93232 tty7     Ss+  17:48   0:49 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
root      1170  0.0  0.0  15856  2064 tty1     Ss+  17:48   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
tjaart    5889  0.0  0.0   9492  2184 pts/1    S+   21:17   0:00 grep tty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which display manager are you using? I had a similar problem when I switched to GDM while testing something. Switching back to SDDM resolved the issue. Apparently there's something in GDM's configuration which prevents vt switching.

Comment: I was using LightDM. Switching to SDDM fixed it for me. Thanks!