# Can't switch to tty1

Tags: login, tty

From time to time I find it handy to switch away from desktop to a terminal. Recently however I lost the ability to switch vt's using either ctrl-alt-fx and chvt x, where x is anything from 1 to 12. Ubuntu 15.10.

```
# systemctl status getty@tty1.service
● getty@tty1.service - Getty on tty1
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since zo 2016-02-28 13:11:10 CET; 4min 4s ago
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
 Main PID: 14153 (agetty)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-getty.slice/getty@tty1.service
           └─14153 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux

feb 28 13:11:10 minivanes systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
```

But sometimes I get these extra lines for this command:

```
feb 28 13:23:58 minivanes login[28686]: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
feb 28 13:23:58 minivanes login[28686]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=
```

# chvt 1 (or anything to 12) just does nothing.

```
# chvt 1
# ls -sla /dev/tty
0 crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 feb 28 13:04 /dev/tty
# ls -sla /dev/tty0
0 crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 0 feb 28 13:03 /dev/tty0
# ls -sla /proc/self/fd/0 
0 lrwx------ 1 root root 64 feb 28 13:21 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
```

Update: It gets weirder: If I logout from desktop session to sddm greeter, I have vt switching back (from greeter and next desktop session after loging in again).

Update 2: Seems there's more problems with dm's, but I'm experiencing it exactly the other way round: [Can't vt Switch in Kubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649644/cant-vt-switch-in-kubuntu-15-04) and here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252404 but I don't have another dm running?

Update 3: If I chvt 2 as root (in xterm) and run fgconsole, it says I'm on 2, but my desktop never disappeared. This starts to feel like a driver bug more and more?

Comment: Did you try to switch to tty2. It might be that your X server is running on tty2.

Comment: not working tty's are most likely related to your video card driver. Try switching from prop to open or from open to prop.

Comment: I'm using intel i915 and use the intel repo for latest stable releases. Would be a shame if that's the problem? Anyway, there's no prop version to switch to, only downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Problems fixed by upgrade to Xenial 16.04